# Zxing without Actionbar

Tags: android, android-camera, libraries, qr-code, zxing

Hello guys I have a problem , I added to my project on android studio the  ZXing libraries ( ZXing - 2.1.jar ) . This is my code :

```
        qrReader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            intent.putExtra("isfullScreen", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

This is the result :

http://postimg.org/image/6bv9udssp/

How do I remove that awful green bar ?

Comment: You seem to be invoking the stand-alone Barcode Scanner app by Intent, but that's not what your question states or what the screen shot shows. You show some other app.

Comment: did you find any way to put it without importing the zxing library?